# Count tbody's Between Two `theads`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a simple table that has this structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
            <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to count how many `tbody`'s exist between two `thead`'s using jQuery (or plain Javascript). Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Xeon06 That's not my code. That HTML is coming from another page, which I'm parsing using jQuery.

Comment: @NathanCampos *shrugs*, just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic function

```
function countHeader(pos1, pos2) {
   return $('table thead:eq('+ pos1 +')').nextUntil('thead:eq('+ pos2 +')').length;
}
```

Use:

```
countHeader(0, 1); // from first to second

countHeader(1, 2); // from second to third
```

#### Note

Your markup is wrong, avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the markup is not valid, but for your example you can use something like this:

```
$("table thead:first")​​​​.nextUntil("thead").length​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XUjcr/

Comment: But and if I want to get the count from the second `<thead>` to the third `<thead>`?

Comment: @NathanCampos Use `:eq(1)` selector (and so on) instead of `:first`.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simplified iterator to get all `tbody` length between `theads`

```
var tbodyM = [];
$('table thead').each (function (idx) {
    tbodyM.push($(this).nextUntil('thead').length);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XUjcr/2/